# "Resetting" the arguments of a variable

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to reset the arguments in the variable def sequence when a user inputs an invalid sequence. Otherwise I get a RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded error because the argument stored in def sequence remains invalid. Any suggestions? I was thinking of putting "self.sequence(None)" in else: but that just adds another argument to def sequence it seems.

```
from tkinter import *

class AT_content_calculator:

    def __init__(self, master):
        #initialising various widgets
        frame_1 = Frame(master)
        frame_1.pack()

        self.varoutput_1 = StringVar()

        self.label_1 = Label(frame_1, text="Please enter a DNA sequence:")
        self.label_1.pack()
        self.entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=self.sequence)
        self.entry_1.pack()
        self.output_1 = Label(frame_1, textvariable=self.varoutput_1)
        self.output_1.pack()
        self.button_1 = Button(frame_1, text="Calculate", command=self.validation_check)
        self.button_1.pack()

    def sequence(self):
     self.dna_sequence = self.entry_1.get()
     return self.dna_sequence

    def validation_check(self):
        #used to validate that self.dna_sequence only contains letters G, C, A, T
        valid = 'GCAT'
        condition = all(i in valid for i in self.sequence())
        if condition:
            self.at_calculate()
        else:
            self.varoutput_1.set("Invalid DNA sequence. Please enter again.")
            self.validation_check()

    def at_calculate(self):
        #used to calculate AT content of string stored in self.dna_sequence
        self.dna_sequence = self.entry_1.get()
        self.total_bases = len(self.dna_sequence)
        self.a_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("A")
        self.b_bases = self.dna_sequence.count("T")
        self.at_content = "%.2f" % ((self.a_bases + self.b_bases) / self.total_bases)
        self.varoutput_1.set("AT content percentage: " + self.at_content)

root = Tk()
root.title("AT content calculator")
root.geometry("320x320")
b = AT_content_calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't anything to do with "resetting" the value of a variable. The problem is just that you repeatedly call `validation_check` from within itself without changing the value being validated, so naturally you end up with a recursion error. You shouldn't call the method again at all: you already show a message telling the user the validation has failed, so just do nothing and wait for them to change the value and press the button again.

(And looping would be much better here than recursion, anyway; but as I say you don't need to do either, just let the method end.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I add self.entry_1.delete(0, END) after Else: I sort of get the result I want but then a division by 0 error..